# Unable To Call Javascript With Enqueue

Tags: javascript

I am using a child theme and trying to call custom JS from /child-theme/js/custom.js

In my function file I have:

```
function myprefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_enqueue_scripts' );
```

In Javascript I have:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "Here's your javascript!" );
});

var textID = document.getElementById("logo.no-image"); // go and take the Text from the ID
var text = textID.innerHTML; // Take the text from the
var toChange = text.split(""); // Separrate each letter into array
var newText = ""; // buffer text
var aClassName = ["red", "green", "blue"]; // class name that you want
var colorNumber = 0; // counter to loop into your class

for (var i=0, ii=toChange.length; i<ii; i++){
        if(colorNumber == aClassName.length){ // if you reach the end of your class array
        colorNumber = 0; //Set it back to 0
    }
    // Add between each letter the span with your class
    newText += "<span class="+aClassName[colorNumber]+">"+toChange[i]+"<\/span>";
    colorNumber++
}
// Output your text into the web
textID.innerHTML = newText;
```

I included the alert to test whether or not the script is being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP jQuery works in compatibility mode by default. It means that the typical $ shortcut for jQuery doesn't work, so it doesn't conflict with any other JavaScript libraries that use the dollar sign also, like MooTools or Prototype.

So you should use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your JS file.

Of course you can wrap the code in an anonymous function where you pass in `jQuery` to be mapped to `$`.

```
(function($) {

    // $ Works here!
    // console.log($);

})( jQuery );
```

You also have to add jquery as a dependency when you enqueue the script:

```
function myprefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_enqueue_scripts' );
```

PS. I assume that your file is enqueued properly and it really is in your code.